# How to specify controller name in test::unit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testunit

I have my brands controller in `app/controllers/merchant/brands_controller.rb`

I'm trying to write a functional test for it. I've defined test class as

```
require 'test_helper'

class Merchant::BrandsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
include Devise::TestHelpers

setup do
    @user = users(:one)
    sign_in @user
    @brand= brands(:one)
end

test "should get index" do
    get :index
    assert_response :success
end
end
```

but the tests throw an error saying

```
ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches {:controller=>"merchant/brands", :action=>"new"}
```

Why is it using 'merchant/brands' as controller name?
Or can I specify custom route to make a request to 'new' method?

My routes look like this

```
namespace :merchant do
  resources :accounts do
    resources :brands
  end
end
```

I

Answer (score 0):

It seems you forgot the accounts part of your route.

Try with

```
class Merchant::Accounts::BrandsControllerTest
```

Comment: My routes are slightly different. Would that cause a trouble?

Comment: Can you please paste them into a gist or similar so I can see what's wrong ?

Comment: It says uninitialized constant when I tried your solution. My controller is in 'merchant' folder that's why I added 'Merchant' scope to my class definition

Comment: But is your BrandsController class in Marchant module? If not, there is not need to qualify it with Marchant namespace.

Comment: yes it is in merchant module. If i don't use scope resolution operator, it will throw an error saying "can't find BrandsController'